# Sql Query timeout from C#

Tags: c#, sql, timeout

I have the following query which insert data from one table to another table. The total number of records this query returns is 270

```
insert into Archive_failedMailLog (logID,logdate,refID,ref,toadd,sub,body,exMessage,Name)
 select logID,logdate,refID,ref,toadd,sub,body,exMessage,u.firstname +' '+ u.lastname 
from failedMailLog   
 join users u on u.empid=failedMailLog.refid 
where logdate>='01 Oct 2014' and logdate<='01 Jan 2015'
```

This query runs fine in SQL Management Studio in less than a second, but when I try to execute this query in C# it gets timeout

Now If I try to change the query which return 10 to 15 records than it works fine in c#.

I tried to change sqlcommand.CommandTimeout=200 but it didn't work.

Please help

My problem is resolved now, Actually I started a begin tran on the table and than forget to either commit or roll back. But now it is working fine.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: How are you calling this from your C# code?

Comment: Update your question and add the C# code you are using to call this script.

Comment: In SqlServer, run "set arithabort off" before running that script. Is it still fast? If not, you're probably dealing with parameter sniffing. Read all about it here: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html (if it's still fast, then yeah, like been said, post your code).